# Headless JS site testing with test for each page

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless

I'm trying to write headless integration tests for every page on my site in CoffeeScript/Javascript and run them in one command. I've tried using casperjs but I keep running into [issues](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/BRaMRyFMOBo) When attempting to run more than one test suite in a loop of requests.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
for page in ['/products','/about', '/contact']
   open(page, ->
       require("tests/#{page}/test.coffee").execute()
```

Where the test file looks something like:

```
exports.execute ->
    test.assert(pageTitleIs('about us'))
```

So that I could keep tests for each page in separate files, but run them all heedlessly with one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
casper.thenOpen( url, ->
  @CurrentUrl = url
  @currentRoute = route
  @test.currentSuite = @test.running = @test.started = false # Hack. If we don't do this and a test fails, no tests after it will be executed
  @test.info("Testing #{urlPath}");
  path = currentDirectory+'/root'+route;
  if(fs.isDirectory(path))
    for file in fs.list(path)
      if(file.indexOf('.spec')!=-1)
        @echo 'executing file: ' + path + '/'+ file
        @test.exec(path + '/'+ file);
  @test.exec currentDirectory+"/smoke.test.js"
  @waitFor ->
    if test_done #Hack. If we don't do this, new tests will start before old ones finished.
      return true
    test_done = false
)
```

This is the solution I came up with, where smoke.test.js gets executed for every page. It's pretty hacky and I've run into many issues related to the scope of the tests, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation does not work with single quotes. You have to use double-quotes. See the difference:

```
require('tests/#{page}/test.coffee').execute()
# becomes: require('tests/#{page}/test.coffee').execute();

require("tests/#{page}/test.coffee").execute()
# becomes: require("tests/" + page + "/test.coffee").execute();
```

Comment: This wasn't so much a coffeescript question but I've edited it.